# Confusion regarding Matrix representation of Lorentz transformation in Jackson

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, inertial-frames

In Jackson (3rd edition p. 545) there are the following equations:
$$A = e^L \tag{11.87}$$
$$\det A = \det(e^L) = e^{Tr L}$$
$$g\widetilde{A}g = A^{-1} \tag{11.88}$$
$$ A = e^L  , g\widetilde{A}g = e^{{g\widetilde{L}g}} , A^{-1} = e^{-L}$$
$$ g\widetilde{L}g = -L $$

$\widetilde{A} $ is the transpose of $A$. I have several doubts:

1. How is it derived the equation $\det(e^L) = e^{TrL}$? Are we assuming a special type of $L$?
2. In $ g\widetilde{A}g = e^{{g\widetilde{L}g}}$, how is it possible to have $g = e^{g}$?

Comment: For your first question, no there is no need to make any special assumptions on $L$ (though Jackson seems to assume $L$ is diagonalizable... which is unnecessary). Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318169/568204

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The property $\det(e^L) = e^{Tr L}$ follows from the matrix identity \begin{equation}
   \log \det (M) = Tr \log(M) \to \det(M) = e^{\text{Tr}\, log (M)}
   \end{equation}
   Choosing $M=e^L$ yields $\,\det(e^L) = e^{\text{Tr}\, L}$.
2. The second property can be shown using a Taylor expansion for the matrix $L$ if we assume $g^2=1$. Suppose we want to show that \begin{equation}g \,e^\tilde{L} g = e^{g \tilde{L} g} \end{equation}
   By expanding the l.h.s. one has 
   \begin{equation}
   g \,e^\tilde{L} g = g\left( 1 + \tilde{L} + \frac{1}{2}\tilde{L}^2+...
    \right) g.
   \end{equation}
   Expanding the r.h.s. we have
   \begin{equation}
   e^{g \tilde{L} g} = 1 + g \tilde{L} g+\frac{1}{2} g \tilde{L} g \cdot g \tilde{L} g + ...
   \end{equation}
   Assuming $g^2=\mathbb{1}$ the two expressions agree.

Comment: So here L is Lorentz transformation matrix? if not what is it? what about S and K given on next page in Jackson?

Comment: @anbhadane Surely are the generators of the Lorentz group. $K$ for the boosts, $S$ for rotations.

Comment: I don't understand how the equality follows from $g^2=1$ ?  This gets you the first and second terms, but the third term requires $g\tilde{L}g\cdot g\tilde{L}g=g\tilde{L}^2g$.  How does the third term (and higher ones) work out ?

Comment: 3rd order: $g \tilde{L} g \cdot g \tilde{L} g \cdot g \tilde{L} g = g \tilde{L} g^2 \tilde{L} g^2 \tilde{L} g = g \tilde{L}  \mathbb{1} \tilde{L}  \mathbb{1} \tilde{L} g = g \tilde{L}^3 g$. This can be extended to the general $Nth$ order by mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Eq. (11.88) is derived from
$$ \widetilde{A}g A~=~g, \tag{11.86} $$
which reveals that it should really read
$$ g^{-1}\widetilde{A}g ~=~A^{-1}. \tag{11.88'} $$
Note that in many books the shorthand notation for the inverse metric $(g^{-1})^{\alpha\beta}$ is $g^{\alpha\beta}$. Also Jackson is talking about the Minkowski metric $g_{\alpha\beta}={\rm diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ in SR where the metric and inverse metric have the same component matrix.

Comment: so L is Lorentz transformation matrix? am i right? what about S and K(on next page)?